# Representable: How to represent a list without a parent node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm using [Representable gem](https://github.com/apotonick/representable) to map from a JSON return.

The JSON returned is like:

```
[

{
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
  "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:05:09-03:00",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "createdAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
  "updatedAt": "2014-05-08T18:08:39-03:00",
}
]
```

But I don't know how to represent it without a parent node as described [here](https://github.com/apotonick/representable#collections).

My representers is like:

```
module Representers
  module OrdersCollectionRepresenter
    include Representable::JSON
    collection :list, extend: Representers::OrderCollectionItemRepresenter,
      class: OrderCollectionItem
  end
end

module Representers
  module OrderCollectionItemRepresenter
    include Representable::JSON

    property :id

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MultiJson.load(json).map { |hash| Representers::OrderCollectionItemRepresenter.from_hash(hash) }
```